# Combining non-mutually exclusive indicator variables with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 x = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4), b = c("g1","g2","g3","g4"), 
 dummy_1 = c(1,1,1,0), dummy_2 = c(0,0,1,1))

 a  b dummy_1 dummy_2
 1 g1       1       0
 2 g2       1       0
 3 g3       1       1
 4 g4       0       1
```

I want to modify my dataframe so that duplicate rows are added when the indicator variables overlap. and combine all my indicator variables into one column. ie, I want my dataframe to end up looking like this

```
a b  dummy 
1 g1 dummmy_1       
2 g2 dummmy_1       
3 g3 dummmy_1  
3 g3 dummmy_2       
4 g4 dummmy_2
```

What is the best method to duplicate the rows and then combine my indicator variables in this way? I've tried using `unite()` but am having a bit of trouble formulating the conditions for duplicating rows in my data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We `gather` into 'long' format, then `filter` out the elements in 'val' that are zero and `select` the relevant columns

```
library(tidyerse)
gather(x, dummy, val, dummy_1:dummy_2) %>% 
       filter(val!=0) %>%
       select(-val)
# a  b   dummy
#1 1 g1 dummy_1
#2 2 g2 dummy_1
#3 3 g3 dummy_1
#4 3 g3 dummy_2
#5 4 g4 dummy_2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
df <- reshape2::melt(x, id.vars = c("a","b"))

df[df$value == 1, c("a","b","variable")]
#  a  b variable
#1 1 g1  dummy_1
#2 2 g2  dummy_1
#3 3 g3  dummy_1
#7 3 g3  dummy_2
#8 4 g4  dummy_2
```

Comment: Thanks! Is reshape2 a part of the tidyverse or is it seperate?

Comment: @AjjitNarayanan I don't think it is loaded by `library(tidyverse)` however it is written by Hadley.